# Cross Origin Reques blocked

Tags: reactjs, api, nginx, axios, cors

I'm trying to load images from an orthanc server with ReactJS. As orthanc doesn't support CORS I've set up a proxy server with nginx. Nginx and orthanc are in docker containers, and nginx can talk to orthanc via http://orthanc:8042.
Following my nginx config file:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
   server {
      listen 80 default;
      server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;
   
      location  /orthanc/  {
         proxy_pass http://orthanc:8042;
         proxy_set_header HOST $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

         rewrite /orthanc(.*) $1 break;
         add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true';
         add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
         add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
         add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'; 
          
      }
   }
}
```

If I try the request with postman the CORS headers from nginx seem to work:

[Postman response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeacI.png)

But if I try to call the api via ReactJS / axios I'm getting blocked by the CORS policies:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8085/orthanc/instances/5cd65944-8a37c5f3-ecd23660-3238d171-41728b44/preview. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).


Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8085/orthanc/instances/5cd65944-8a37c5f3-ecd23660-3238d171-41728b44/preview. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

And here is my request:

```
import axios from 'axios'
export const PacsService = {
    find,
    authToken,
}
function  find() {
    authToken()
    var response = instance.get('http://localhost:8085/orthanc/instances/5cd65944-8a37c5f3-ecd23660-3238d171-41728b44/preview')
    console.log(response.data)

     
}

// -- Axios https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults
const instance =  axios.create({
    //baseURL: `${config.ORTHANC_BASE_URL}`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})

instance.interceptors.request.use(request => {
    console.log('Starting Request', JSON.stringify(request, null, 2))
    return request
})

instance.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    console.log('Response:', JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))
    console.log(response)
    return response
    
})

// -- Helper functions
export function authToken() {
    // set default header to be sent with every request
    instance.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling with Postman you only send a `GET` request.
Browsers always send a `OPTIONS` request first to check the CORS rules.

You simply forward every request to the orthanc Server with your nginx rules. But orthanc does not support `OPTIONS` requests and will send you an error response - for example `error 404`. When this happens, the browser blocks your requests due to CORS errors. You should be able to recreate this error with Postman by sending a `OPTIONS` request instead of a `GET` request to your orthanc URL.

As a workaround you can configure the nginx to return code `200 OK` everytime a `OPTIONS` request is sent to your orthanc server. The response must also include the `Access-Control-Allow` headers to let the Browsers know that CORS is allowed. In your case this would look something like this:

```
      location  /orthanc/  {
         # always return code 200 with needed CORS headers
         if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            return 200;
         }

         proxy_pass http://orthanc:8042;
         rewrite /orthanc(.*) $1 break;
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      }
```

the `always` Tag at the end of the headers is needed because otherwise it wouldn't return this headers as orthanc does not reply with a `200 OK` response